# Why should I use cell.render("Cell") instead of cell.value in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I'm using `react-table` package. I'm confused, what's the point of `cell.render("Cell")` when I can just write `cell.value`?
I see in my browser that it renders the same way. So, why should I use the first one?

[image: 2022-02-11_22-15-41------]

Answer (score 5):

Because When you define the columns for your table you may want to customize how the Cell is rendered.
Here is an example of one of my columns.

```
{
        Header: "Enable",
        id: "enable",
        accessor: "enable",
        Cell: ({ value, row }) => (
            <FormCheck checked={value} onChange={(e) => handleCheckChange(row.index, e)} />
        ),
},
```

I use the Cell property to customize how each cell will look on the table and I cant add props to the cell like onChange.
If I just used .value instead of .render(Cell) my cells would not have a  Element and I couldn't customize how the value is displayed within the Cell `<td><FormCheck /><td/>`

TLDR: If you want to customize the cells from your column definitions you will want to use the .render("Cell").
In my code example I use the Column option Cell to insert a CheckBox for that column (Does not effect the header () only ())

Comment: Thanks. One more tiny question: For some unusual reason, I want the cells to render their column name instead of cell value. Can I easily get the column name of the cell without this long workaround?

`<td>{tableColumns.find((x) => x.accessor === cell.column.id)?.Header}</td>`

Comment: @leodevbro Yes I believe if you use the `Cell: ({column, value}) => (<td>{column.Header} {value}<td/>)` on your Column definition you can easily add the header to each cell under that column.

Comment: Edit: and if you just want the header and no value it would be. `Cell: ({column}) => (<td>{column.Header}<td/>)`

Comment: Huge thanks. It's working.